# Format chapters except appendix

Tags: titlesec, thesis, appendix

For the thesis I am writing it is demanded that the appendix chapters come in the form of "Appendix A", "Appendix B", etc..

I wanted different formatting for the chapters than the standard one so I used the titlesec package. The formatting of the chapters became what I wanted, but it also removed the "Appendix" word in the appendix's chapters. I am not proficient with the titlesec formatting package, so below I post an example of what I mean in hopes someone can help.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright, dvipsnames]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE\color{MidnightBlue}}{\thechapter\hspace{0pt}\color{MidnightBlue}\hspace{10pt}}{0pt}{\LARGE}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape\large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\color{MidnightBlue}}


\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Intro}
\chapter{Development}
\section{Intro}

\appendix
\chapter{One}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to keep that exact formatting and include the "Appendix" word before ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that in the main part of the document, `\@chapapp` expands to `\chaptername`, but after `\appendix` it expands to `\appendixname`.

Also note the simplifications I made in the rest of the code.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\scshape\LARGE\color{MidnightBlue}}
  {\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\appendixname\ \fi\thechapter}
  {10pt}
  {\LARGE}
\makeatother

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape\large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\color{MidnightBlue}}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Intro}
\chapter{Development}
\section{Intro}

\appendix
\chapter{One}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the additional simplification.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\chaptername` stores, what to display in a chapter head (e.g. in English it is `Chapter`, in German it's `Kapitel`).
Same goes for `\appendixname` for appendices (`Appendix` or `Anhang`).

The command `\chaptertitlename` chooses, depending on whether you are in the `\appendix` or not, which of these two is called.

You could add `\chaptertitlename` to your `titlesec` definition and adjust the two commands above like this:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix }
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE\color{MidnightBlue}}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter\hspace{0pt}\color{MidnightBlue}\hspace{10pt}}{0pt}{\LARGE}
```

Comment: Great explanation, it solved the problem too !